# 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'user' snsscrape

Tags: web-scraping

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_68/3657321750.py in <module>
     12         break
     13     #print(i)
---> 14     tweets_list.append([tweet.id,tweet.url,tweet.user.username,tweet.content,tweet.date,source,tweet.retweetCount,tweet.likeCount,tweet.replyCount])
     15 
     16 tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list,columns=['Tweet_ID', 'URL', "Account_Name", 'Text', 'Datetime','Source','Number_Retweets', 'Number_Likes', 'Number_Comments'])

AttributeError: 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'user'
```

**Can anyone let me know why I am getting this error, In local machine it is working fine but in kaggle kernel it is showing this error?**

Answer (score 0):

I also get the problem. I found out that this is due to the version difference. In my local machine, I don't get this problem because the version is 0.4.3. When I use Google Colab, I get the no attribute 'user' problem because the installed version is 0.3.4